# Sterling exception on dispose after saveAsync thousands records

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, sterling-db

I'm trying to populate a sterling db from a SQL db, so I query the SQL get about 6000

```
    _engine = new SterlingEngine(new PlatformAdapter());
    _engine.Activate();
    string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    _databaseInstance = _engine.SterlingDatabase.RegisterDatabase<TCP.Datosejemplol.Sterling.ejemploDatos>("ejemploDatos", new FileSystemDriver(@"E:\pruebaSterling\Otrofolder"));


    BLL.Contextos.ContextoIndices manejoIndices = new BLL.Contextos.ContextoIndices(new BLL.SQL.ManejoIndices());
    var DatosCompleto = manejoIndices.DatosCompleto();

    foreach (var indiceBase in DatosCompleto)
    {
        var indice = new TCP.Datosejemplol.Sterling.Entidades.Indice()
            {
                IdIndice = indiceBase.IdIndice,
                Nombre = indiceBase.Nombre,
                NombreCompleto = indiceBase.NombreCompleto,
                IdIndice_padre = indiceBase.IdIndice_padre,
                EsPadre = indiceBase.EsPadre
            };
        _databaseInstance.SaveAsync<TCP.Datosejemplol.Sterling.Entidades.Indice>(indice);
    }
```

It seems to work fine, but when closing the connection with  _engine.Dispose();

I get the following exception:

```
 InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
   HResult=-2147467261
   Message=Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.
   Source=Wintellect.Sterling.Core
   StackTrace:
        en Wintellect.Sterling.Core.Serialization.AggregateSerializer.Serialize(Object target, BinaryWriter writer) en e:\Proyectos\Sistematizacion\Codigo\TCP.ArbolJurisprudencial\Wintellect.Sterling.Core\Serialization\AggregateSerializer.cs:línea 114
        en Wintellect.Sterling.Server.FileSystem.FileSystemDriver.<SerializeIndexAsync>d__c`2.MoveNext() en e:\Proyectos\Sistematizacion\Codigo\TCP.ArbolJurisprudencial\Wintellect.Sterling.Server\FileSystem\FileSystemDriver.cs:línea 129
     --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
        en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
        en Wintellect.Sterling.Core.Indexes.IndexCollection`3.<SerializeIndexesAsync>d__8.MoveNext() en e:\Proyectos\Sistematizacion\Codigo\TCP.ArbolJurisprudencial\Wintellect.Sterling.Core\Indexes\IndexCollection.cs:línea 92
     --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
        en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
        en Wintellect.Sterling.Core.Indexes.IndexCollection`3.<FlushAsync>d__c.MoveNext() en e:\Proyectos\Sistematizacion\Codigo\TCP.ArbolJurisprudencial\Wintellect.Sterling.Core\Indexes\IndexCollection.cs:línea 104
     --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
        en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
        en Wintellect.Sterling.Core.Database.BaseDatabaseInstance.<FlushAsync>d__27.MoveNext() en e:\Proyectos\Sistematizacion\Codigo\TCP.ArbolJurisprudencial\Wintellect.Sterling.Core\Database\BaseDatabaseInstance.cs:línea 633
```

I've tried to check on the saveAsync BackgroundWorker if it's completed, and everytime it is.

If I try to save less items in every session everything works fine.
so my question is:

Is there a way to know if the saving has not finished?

Please advice.

BR

Jorge

Comment: Couldn't fix it, but I realized that there is a problem with the indexes, if I delete the indexes the database is reusable again.
I'll try to check on the sterling code later on, maybe there is something to tweak there.

Comment: Another potential problem; if `_databaseInstance.SaveAsync()` returns a task, you need to call `.Wait()` on it. Otherwise you are doing a fire and forget, and might be disposing of `_engine` before `_databaseInstance` has finished its work.

Comment: I also assigned it to an object and performed a check on IsComplete, but it always returned "That the task was already completed" 
Now I changed to SQLite and it's a change of paradigm... when I was getting use to objects.